# Algorithm Trading.The algorithm compares the median of the last m sales prices with the last price. I

Tags: java

I am attaching my code here. I don't know why but I am getting this compile time error. I have tried everything just need help figuring out where I am going wrong. here is the qs

Q) The algorithm compares the median of the last m sales prices with the last price. If this median is greater than the last price, the algorithm recommends that you sell the stock; if the median is equal to the last price, the algorithm recommends that you hold; and if the median is less than the last

ERROR:

```
Solution.java:30: error: cannot find symbol
            if(medianQ.size() == m)
                      ^
  symbol:   method size()
  location: variable medianQ of type IMedianQueue<Integer>

Solution.java:35: error: cannot find symbol
            if(medianQ.size() != m)
                      ^
  symbol:   method size()
  location: variable medianQ of type IMedianQueue<Integer>
Solution.java:38: error: cannot find symbol
            int median = medianQ.getMedian();
                                ^
  symbol:   method getMedian()
  location: variable medianQ of type IMedianQueue<Integer>
Solution.java:74: error: cannot find symbol
         list.append(x);
             ^
  symbol:   method append(int)
  location: variable list of type ArrayList<Integer>
Solution.java:125: error: cannot find symbol
            list.append(x);
                ^
  symbol:   method append(E)
  location: variable list of type MedianQueue<E>
  where E is a type-variable:
    E extends Comparable<? super E> declared in class MedianQueue
Solution.java:132: error: cannot find symbol
            list.removeFirst();
                ^
  symbol:   method removeFirst()
  location: variable list of type MedianQueue<E>
  where E is a type-variable:
    E extends Comparable<? super E> declared in class MedianQueue
Solution.java:139: error: cannot find symbol
            return list.getFirst();
                       ^
  symbol:   method getFirst()
  location: variable list of type MedianQueue<E>
  where E is a type-variable:
    E extends Comparable<? super E> declared in class MedianQueue
Note: Solution.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
7 errors


import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.math.*;
import java.util.regex.*;
import java.util.Collections;


public class Solution {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        // I recommend that you use this approach for IO, rather than a Scanner for
        // speed reasons
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        IMedianQueue<Integer> medianQ = new MedianQueue<>();


        String[] tokens = reader.readLine().split(" ");
        int n = Integer.valueOf(tokens[0]);
        int m = Integer.valueOf(tokens[1]);

        // Collect your output before printing it out (for speed reasons)      
         StringBuffer sbOut = new StringBuffer();

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) 
        {
            int lastPrice = Integer.valueOf(reader.readLine());
            // Do something smarter here

            if(medianQ.size() == m)
                medianQ.dequeue();

            medianQ.enqueue(lastPrice);

            if(medianQ.size() != m)
                continue;

            int median = medianQ.getMedian();

            if (i % 3 == 0)
                sbOut.append("buy\n"); 
            else if (i % 3 == 1)
                sbOut.append("sell\n");
            else
                sbOut.append("hold\n");
            }
              // Output your decisions      
              System.out.print(sbOut.toString());
        }
}

interface IMedian <E extends Comparable<? super E>>
     {
            void add(int x);
            boolean remove(E x);   
            //boolean replace(E oldVal, E newVal);
            E getMedian();
            int size();
     }

class SortedArray<E extends Comparable <? super E>> implements IMedian<E>
{
    private ArrayList<Integer> list;
    private Set set;

    public SortedArray(int m)
    {
        list = new ArrayList<>(m);
    }

    @Override
    public void add(int x)
    {
         list.append(x);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean remove(E x)
    {
        return list.remove(list.get(0));
    }

    /*@Override
    public boolean replace(E oldVal, E newVal)
    {
      boolean replaced = set.remove(oldVal);
      return replaced & set.add(newVal);
    }*/

    @Override
    public int size()
    {
        return list.size();
    }

    public E getMedian()
    {
        ArrayList<E> temp = new ArrayList(list);
        Collections.sort(temp);
        return temp.get(size()/2);
      }
}

interface IMedianQueue<E extends Comparable <? super E>>
     {
        boolean isEmpty();
        void enqueue(E x);
        E dequeue();
        E front();
     }

class MedianQueue<E extends Comparable <? super E>> implements IMedianQueue<E>
{    
        MedianQueue <E> list = new MedianQueue<>();

        @Override
        public boolean isEmpty()
        {
            return list.isEmpty();
        }

        @Override
        public void enqueue(E x)
        {
            list.append(x);
        }

        @Override
        public E dequeue()
        {
            E Returnvalue = front();
            list.removeFirst();
            return Returnvalue;
        }

        @Override
        public E front()
        {
            return list.getFirst();
        }

}
```

Comment: Your ```MedianQueue``` class and  ```IMedianQueue``` interface do not have mentioned methods. ```ArrayList``` doesn't have ```append()``` method.

Comment: @devmind what do you mean by mentioned methods for MedianQueue class and IMedianQueue interface. Sorry I am kind of new to this.

Comment: For example take a look at first three messages. Compiler complains about unknown methods ```size()``` and ```getMedian()``` for variable ```medianQ``` of type ```IMedianQueue<Integer>```. Now take a look at your ```IMedianQueue``` interface. It has only 4 methods: ```isEmpty()```, ```enqueue()```, ```dequeue()```, and ```front()```. That the reason for compilation first 3 errors in the list. Similar situation with others.